# R. errors on my project when referencing ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, adt

The title is very self explanatory. When I try to reference ABS on my project, I get several "**R cannot be resolved to a type**" errors on **MY** project (not in the ABS library, only in my project). I repeat, the error appear on **MY** project, **not** in the ABS Library as all the "help" I've found said.

I hope you are able to help me!

Note: my project's min-sdk: 8, and target-sdk: 19. ABS library min-sdk: 7, and target-sdk: 17 (tried to level the sdk to the same one, but still, no success)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check to see if R is imported at the top of your class

Comment: I've checked it, it's not imported, but also R.java doesn't exists in my project's /gen folder, but if I remove the the ABS library, everything comes to normal on my project and R.java is again in the /gen folder. Don't have a clue of what's going on :/

Comment: sometimes compiling gets glitchy. it is a crude "solution" but you may want to restart your IDE.

Comment: tried that as well, didn't worked :/

Comment: It seems I've solved the problem. Removed ABS reference from my project, R.java appeared in my proj. /gen, copied it to my desktop, added ABS reference, errors everywhere, but the i copied the R.java from my desktop to the /gen folder, and magically, all errors fade away, haven't tested on my phone though... hope this has solved the problem!

Comment: At the end, bad solution, didn't worked.

Comment: Because R.java is a generated file, no changes you make to it will ever persist, and at worse will cause even more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just starting to work with the ActionBar, you should probably use the appcompat v7 library instead of ABS. It provides the same backwards-compatibility with the ActionBar, but it is being developed by Google so it will work much more nicely. In fact, ABS isn't even being developed any longer because of appcompat v7.

Read about the compat libraries here 
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

The developer guide for ActionBar is written with appcompat-v7 in mind
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Yeah, thank you anyway for your answer! But I've already started working with appcompat-v7, since I gave up with ABS, and it's working as expected. Hope this post helps another helpless soul like me hehe, peace!